# Use Verilog module parameter in net declaration connected to module

Tags: verilog

Is there a way to use a parameter of a module in the declaration of a net that's connected to that module? I'm trying to do something like this, but I believe it's failing as the module hasn't been declared yet when the parameter is used.

```
wire [vga.IMAGE_ROW_BUS_SIZE - 1:0] row;
wire [vga.IMAGE_COL_BUS_SIZE - 1:0] col;

vga vga (
    .clk_in(CLK100MHZ),
    
    .image_row(row),
    .image_col(col),
    .image_red(red),
    .image_green(green),
    .image_blue(blue),
    
    .vga_red(VGA_R),
    .vga_green(VGA_G),
    .vga_blue(VGA_B),
    .vga_hsync(VGA_HS),
    .vga_vsync(VGA_VS)
);
```

[image: Verilog Errors]

Comment: Can you change the order and check? I mean put the wire declarations below the instantiation.

Comment: If I do that I get a warning about the nets having already been implicitly declared.

Comment: Hmm looks like a cyclic dependency here. Are the warnings critical? I think it may still work in simulation.

Comment: Still get the same errors if I put the module instantiation above.

Comment: Any way to instantiate the module, declare the nets, then connect them separately from the module instantiation?

Comment: Did you try the usual way of declaring parameters in the upper module, then passing them into the vga module?

Comment: I get the same errors if I try declaring a completely new wire below the module instantiation, so it looks like you just can't use a module instance's parameter in that manner.

Comment: @toolic As the parameter I'm using is a localparam that the module calculates based on it's other parameters, I was hoping to be able to just pull it out of the module instance.

Comment: It compiles and simulates fine in my ModelSim and Vivado though. Which simulator you use?

Comment: Is this synthesis error or compilation/simulation error?

Comment: @MituRaj Synthesis error (Vivado 2020.2)

Comment: I think it's not possible to do in Vivado synthesis flow. Not sure why. If your localparams are dependent on VGA's parameters, then bring those parameters to the top level and pass them to VGA from the top level. Then you can derive those VGA localparams in your top level as well.